# AddChart in a sheet that is not active/selected (VBA Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm trying to create a new chart with the following code:

```
Sheet1.Range("C1:C21").TextToColumns Destination:=Sheet1.Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Sheet1.Select
Set classificacio = Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart2(Style:=-1, XlChartType:=xlBarStacked, Left:=Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Left, Top:=Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Top, Width:=Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(15, 8)).Width, Height:=Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(20, 8)).Height, NewLayout:=True).Chart
classificacio.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Sheet1.Cells(11, 2), Sheet1.Cells(20, 3))
classificacio.HasTitle = False
```

It works. However, it doesn't work when I delete `Sheet1.Select` because the code starts when Sheet3 is active. It seems that `Set classificacio = Sheet1.Shapes...` only makes sense when Sheet1 is the ActiveSheet.

How could I create this chart avoiding the selection of Sheet1, where the chart is created, and keeping always Sheet3 as the ActiveSheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because the Cells object are not fully qualified. If you do not qualify them, then they will refer to the active sheet.

Change `Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(15, 8))` to `Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(15, 8))`. Same with `Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(20, 8))`

Or better still, Put then in a `With-End With` Block (Untested).

```
With Sheet1
    .Range("C1:C21").TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Set classificacio = .Shapes.AddChart2(Style:=-1, XlChartType:=xlBarStacked, _
                                          Left:=.Cells(1, 1).Left, _
                                          Top:=.Cells(1, 1).Top, _
                                          Width:=.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(15, 8)).Width, _
                                          Height:=.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(20, 8)).Height, _
                                          NewLayout:=True).Chart

    classificacio.SetSourceData Source:=Range(.Cells(11, 2), .Cells(20, 3))
    classificacio.HasTitle = False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. What are the advantages of using With - End With? Not only in this case, but also in any other example.

Comment: In this case, you do not have to write `Sheet1` again and again. I would recommend reading about **With Statement** [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)